# Einstein Email Recommendation Implementation

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations

I am new to Einstein email recommendation and trying to implement it. I have read the trail head and salesforce documentation. I have a few questions,

1. Is it not possible to proceed and test the Einstein email recommendation without integrating the Collect Tracking code?  I just want to test the  ‘Display’ . Is a Catalog just enough to test the Display?
2. Is there any website for testing where we can add this tracking code to start with and send data to Einstein?  I first want to test on test website and not on actual one
3. Or can we add this to a cloud page ? If so if anyone can share how to do it? I have the codes from documentation but want to know how and where to place it to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to complete the prereqs before creating/configuring a recommendation, the prereqs are a catalog and collect code
2. there is no test website to install the collect code on you can install this on your dev site
3. Yes you can install the collect code on a cloudpage, you would simply follow the instructions in the collect code

Answer (score 0):

1. You must collect data via collect to move past the FTUX (first-time user experience) screen. Because recommendation lists are built off this data, it is required to have that setup before testing.
2. You can use any HTML to test (or even simulate calls in a browser via URL). You can add collect to any test, dev, staging site before pushing to production or even use MC CloudPages.
3. Yes, you can use a cloudpage.  You will just need to follow the setup in the help docs (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_ctc_install_collect_code.htm&type=5).

You will want to ensure the var _etmc = []; is in your code for CloudPages (it may not be in all the examples, so make sure to check it).

```
  var _etmc = [];
  _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "XXXXXX"]);
  _etmc.push(["setUserInfo", {"email": "XXXXXX"}]);
  _etmc.push(["trackPageView", { "item" : "XXXXXX" }]);
```